# Cheerio each loop does not break out early

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

In the Cheerio/Jquery [documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) it is stated, that return false should break each loop early.

I have the following code:

```
"use strict";
let cheerio = require('cheerio');
let $ = cheerio.load('<a href="www.test.com"></a><a href="www.test.com"></a>');

$('a').each(function(index,value){
  console.log(index);
  return false;
});
```

It should, in my head, print 0 to console, but it prints 0 and 1. What am I missing?

Comment: the code is fine, it will print only 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine. If you look at cheerio's source code, you can see that there is no way the loop continues if you return false.

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/master/lib/api/traversing.js#L298

```
exports.each = function(fn) {
  var i = 0, len = this.length;
  while (i < len && fn.call(this[i], i, this[i]) !== false) ++i;
  return this;
};
```

Comment: Something wrong with my environment then. After copying it to another VM, it works as it should.